# Django: exclude objects based on another model

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a model `Comment`:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    upload = models.ForeignKey(Upload, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And I also have a model `BlockedUser`:

```
class BlockedUser(models.Model):
    blocked_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blocked_by")
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

How can I fetch all the comments except ones written by someone who you've blocked?

```
queryset = Comment.objects.all().select_related('user')
queryset = queryset.exclude(user__in=BlockedUser.objects.filter(blocked_by=self.request.user))
```

Which obviously doesn't work like that, but I am not sure how to write it so that it does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude `Comment`s from a `user` for which there exists a `BlockedUser` with `blocked_by` the `request.user` with:

```
Comment.objects.exclude(user__blockeduser__blocked_by=request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This `__` relationship stuff is still a bit magical to me, hard to understand which relationships are available.